# IOS Webkit Debug proxy issue - Unable to bind device

Tags: java, ios, ipad, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to start ios webkit debug proxy by passing the udid and the port number.

Command: `ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c 4ea8dd11e8c4fbc1a2deadbeefa0fd3bbbb268c7:27753 -d`.

Facing issue while binding the device on port number 27753. Error message,'*Unable to bind udid on port 27753-27753*'

Answer (score 0):

Check this web link https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/ios-webkit-debug-proxy.md, if it helps.

Comment: It doesn't. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it cannot be bind to the port since it's already taken.
Check if the port is taken by another process (or same type of process that is hanged by some reason) by running `sof -t -i tcp:27753` command in terminal.

To find and kill process run `sof -t -i tcp:27753 | xargs kill` command in terminal, but it's not safe to do in case if you have parallel execution and/or not only `ios_webkit_debug_proxy` is using port `27753`.